# Get Data from Stored Procedure in Entity Framework without Entity on function return

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

This is my stored procedure, a bit complex

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spx_SELECT_Etiquetas]
@Localizacao nvarchar(20),
@LocalizacaoID int = NULL,
@Armazem int

AS
BEGIN


SET NOCOUNT ON 

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX); 
    IF(@Armazem = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'SELECT Etiqueta, xl.LocalizacaoID
                FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, ''SELECT ET0101 AS Etiqueta,
                                                ET0109 AS Localizacao

                                         FROM (         
                                                SELECT DISTINCT FET001.ET0109,  FET001.ET0101
                                                FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.FET001 FET001
                                                WHERE (FET001.ET0104=''''POE'''') AND (FET001.ET0105=''''DIS'''') AND FET001.ET0109 = (''''' + @Localizacao + ''''')                                
                                         ) AS AUTO '') AS mc
                 LEFT JOIN xLocalizacao xl
                 ON xl.Localizacao = mc.Localizacao
                 WHERE LocalizacaoID = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@LocalizacaoID) + '
                 UNION
                 SELECT Etiqueta, xe.LocalizacaoID FROM xEtiquetas xe
                 WHERE xe.LocalizacaoID = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@LocalizacaoID) + '
                 ORDER BY Etiqueta DESC';
    END
    ELSE IF(@Armazem = 2)
    BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT Etiqueta, xl.LocalizacaoID
                FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, ''SELECT LBLBNB AS Etiqueta,
                                                GHNEMP AS Localizacao

                                         FROM (         
                                                SELECT DISTINCT GA160H.GHNEMP, GA160H.LBLBNB
                                                FROM D805DATPOR.GA160H GA160H, D805DATPOR.GA160M GA160M
                                                WHERE GA160M.LBLBNB = GA160H.LBLBNB AND (GA160H.GHZORI=''''CORRICA'''') AND (GA160H.GHCSTA=''''DIS'''') AND GA160H.GHNEMP = (''''' + @Localizacao + ''''')                              
                                         ) AS AUTO '') AS mc
                 LEFT JOIN xLocalizacao xl
                 ON xl.Localizacao = mc.Localizacao
                 WHERE LocalizacaoID = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@LocalizacaoID) + '
                 UNION
                 SELECT Etiqueta, xe.LocalizacaoID FROM xEtiquetas xe
                 WHERE xe.LocalizacaoID = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@LocalizacaoID) + '
                 ORDER BY Etiqueta DESC';
    END                             
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

END
```

It gets Etiquetas from a local table and also from a table in a linked server.
The Output is the columns Etiquetas and Localizacao

However i have a table to save locally new Etiquetas that are added so i have  the following class generated by EF

```
public partial class xEtiquetas
{
    public int EtiquetaID { get; set; }
    public int Etiqueta { get; set; }
    public int LocalizacaoID { get; set; }

    public virtual xLocalizacao xLocalizacao { get; set; }
}
```

this is my get controller. Basically the relation is

```
Inventarios > Localizacoes > Etiquetas
```

the x is just a prefix identifier cause there are different applications using the same database by other coworkers separated by a prefix.

Also I have to get the Etiquetas separately using the stored procedure since it's coming from a linked server. (Unless there's another way)

```
public IQueryable<InventarioModel> Get()
    {
        InventarioCiclicoContext db = new InventarioCiclicoContext();

        var inventarios = db.xInventario.Select(
            i => new InventarioModel { 
                                    InventarioID = i.InventarioID, 
                                    Colaborador = i.xColaborador.Nome,
                                    Armazem = i.xArmazem.Armazem,
                                    Estado = i.EstadoInventario,
                                    Data = i.DataCriacao,
                                    Localizacoes = i.xLocalizacao.Select(
                                    l => new LocalizacaoModel {
                                                                 LocalizacaoID = l.LocalizacaoID,
                                                                 Localizacao = l.Localizacao,
                                                                 EtiquetasPorInventariar = l.EtiquetasPorInventariar,
                                                                 EtiquetasInventariadas = l.EtiquetasInventariadas,
                                                                 Valid = l.IsValid,
                                                                 Precisao = l.Precisao,
                                                                 InventarioID = l.InventarioID
                                                             }).ToList()
                                });

        string localizacao = ".MP3-D16";
        int? localizacaoID = 1;
        int? armazem = 1;

        var etiquetas = db.spx_SELECT_Etiquetas(localizacao, localizacaoID, armazem);

        return inventarios.ToList().AsQueryable();
    }
```

The SP returns -1. I tried using Entity return type but it does not work cause the local table generated is only for the created so the columns returned from the linked server won't make me able to use this.

I created an EtiquetaModel class

```
public class EtiquetaModel
{
    public int Etiqueta { get; set; }
    public string Localizacao { get; set; } 
}
```

Is there a way to get the output from the SP to this class? I can't even use ToList() on it.

Comment: Why are you using unparametrised dynamic SQL, when the SQL doesn't even need to be dynamic?

Comment: Are you talking about the stored procedure?

Comment: Yes. You shouldn't be doing things like `LocalizacaoID = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@LocalizacaoID) + '`. Your code should simply be `LocalizacaoID = @LocalizacaoID` and then you should be passing `@LocalizacaoID` as a paramter to `sp_executesql`; however, this SQL doesn't need to be dynamic, there's nothing dynamic about it.

Comment: Could you show me an example of doing this? I'm not much into this, i had some help doing this query and this was suggested to me

Comment: Ahh, you do have a small dynamic part. I'll post a safer version for you shortly `''''' + @Localizacao + '''''`

Comment: I would personally do [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0640b778901ff8b3c8bf8507664ef2c1). Note that I have changed `''''' + @Localizacao + '''''` to `''' + QUOTENAME(@Localizacao, N'''') + N'''` and then parametrised the `sp_executesql`.

Comment: interesting, didn't know you could pass more stuff to executesql